# CSS3 transforms causing very strange window.scrollY behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm using some newer CSS on a Wordpress site I'm building, including `vh` to make sections the height of the viewport, and `transform-z` for parallax scrolling effects.

I noticed that although the page scrolls normally, no matter where I am on the page `window.scrollY` or `$(window).scrollTop()` will return 0. That is, unless I try to scroll beyond the boundaries of the page, in which case it does begin to return real values (elastic scrolling on a Mac).

In fact, an event listener for `$(window).scroll()` doesn't even fire until I hit the page boundaries.

Has anyone else encountered anything like this? I don't even know where to begin debugging this... I am currently logging `$(window).scrollTop()` to the console on scroll to illuminate the problem.

http://dev.nickforddesign.com/resonator/category/portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should remove the `main`'s overflow statement, and move it to sections.

```
section { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
main {
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Then your event will fire, and you'll be able to change each section's `scrollTop` via js.

Comment: This was not the entire solution, the height on `main` was another factor, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encapsulating your `$(window).scrollTop()` inside of an `.on()` method?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   $(this).scrollTop();
});
```

Comment: @HexLuthor Perhaps share a jsfiddle or something so I can demo and help debug.